# Thread Safe String Split

Tags: java, performance, split

I have ran a split test with StringTokenizer and String's method indexOf() followed by substring(). After result I have to knew, the second one is faster than StringTokenizer. But my question is which is best for Thread safety?

String split using StringTokenizer:

```
String sample=null;
StringTokenizer tokens = new StringTokenizer("FF#Mukil","#");

if(tokens.hasMoreTokens())
{
    sample= tokens.nextToken();
    System.out.println(sample);
}
```

String split using String's method:

```
String sample= "FF#Mukil";
int pos=sample.indexOf('#');
System.out.println(sample.substring(0,pos));
```

In these examples, sample is global variable
Thanks in advance

Edited:
In Previous first example is like below

```
StringTokenizer tokens = new StringTokenizer("FF#Mukil","#");

    if(tokens.hasMoreTokens())
    {
        String sample= tokens.nextToken();
        System.out.println(sample);
    }
```

I have changed it like below

```
String sample=null;
StringTokenizer tokens = new StringTokenizer("FF#Mukil","#");

    if(tokens.hasMoreTokens())
    {
        sample= tokens.nextToken();
        System.out.println(sample);
    }
```

Edited: Added java file source.

```
//FileName=MySplitUtil.java
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;
public class MySplitUtil
{
    public static void setUsername_locale(HttpServletRequest request)
    {
        String value = (String) request.getAttribute("userLocale"); // userLocale's sample value looks like ffmukil$en_US
        splite1(value,request);
        splite2(value,request);
    }
    private static void splite1(String value,HttpServletRequest request)
    {
        StringTokenizer tokens = new StringTokenizer(value,"$");
        String username=null;
        String locale=null;
        if(tokens.hasMoreTokens())
        {
            username = tokens.nextToken();
            locale = tokens.nextToken();
        }
        request.setAttribute("usrName",username);
        request.setAttribute("usr_Locale",locale);
    }
    private static  void splite2(String value,HttpServletRequest request)
    {
        int pos = value.indexOf('$');
        String username = value.substring(0,pos);
        String locale = value.substring(pos+1,value.length());
        request.setAttribute("usrName",username);
        request.setAttribute("usr_Locale",locale);
    }
}
```

Comment: I dont see any of issue your code have in multithreaded environment.

Comment: Can you show how your variables might be used in a multi-threaded environment?  Your current code shows no need for synchronization.

Comment: @Jayamohan, How did you check that? Can you tell me?

Comment: @JoshDM, I have an web-app using Apache server and Struts1 framework. I am using that example at one action file.

Comment: @FF Mukil - according to your code, you appear to only declare and use your variables in METHOD SCOPE.  If all of the code above is in methods, even if those methods are hit by multiple threads simultaneously, there is no point where the actions of either thread would affect the data referred to by the other thread.  If your variables were declared CLASS scope, then we'd have a problem, but as it stands, there is no multithreading issue here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since you only use local variables, both versions are perfectly safe, whatever you do with them...

To run into thread safety issues, you need to (improperly) share something across threads. Nothing can be shared in your example.

More generally, Strings are immutable and therefore thread safe. So the second version, assuming that the `sample` variable is shared, would be thread safe.

**EDIT**

Your latest edit confirms 2 things:

- your class is stateless (no instance variables)
- you only use local variables

So both methods are thread safe and you should choose the simpler and/or more efficient one.

Comment: assylias,
excuse me. I have made some changes with local variable (sample).

Comment: @FFMukil Your edit is still unclear - show the code of your class, with the relevant fields (sample?) and methods.

Answer (score 1):

In java, `Strings` are immutable, nothing will affect the original string.

That immutability makes the `Strings` thread safe. It can be accesses by several `StringTokenizer` or `string.substring` at the same time without any problems.

However, the problem could come from the class `StringTokenizer` that you should not use on several strings at the same time. But, as pointed out by others, in your code you are only using local variables, so you won't have thread safety issues.

Comment: First of all Thanks for the reply. I have used sample as a global variable. Here only I have changed it as local variable.

Answer (score 0):

According to the Javadoc: "A StringTokenizer object internally maintains a current position within the string to be tokenized. Some operations advance this current position past the characters processed."

So it's not threadsafe. Why would you want to share it anyway? Just make it a local variable.